# Pinterest Buyable Pins Magento Integration

Tags: magento-1.9, api

just fascinated by the new pinterest concept of buyable pins . Where customer can buy products (marked by 'buy it'  blue button) from pinterest itself without redirecting to our magento store . Although for processing the product i.e at checkout process , magento's payment system is used .

Now as i assume it's done by magento's SOAP API triggered at pinterest for starting two-way communication b/w magento store and pinterest . I have good idea about magento system but not for pinterest .

Although there's an extension worth 499 dollars but i am trying to build buyable pins for our magento store's product myself . After searching a lot can't find any good developer resource for creating buyable pins .

So if anybody can provide me hints on how to create it or any helpful links . Thanks .

Answer (score 1):

Great question! There's not a way to build one yourself. For each ecommerce platform Pinterest integrates with, they have selected one integration as the approved integration. This is because of the complexity of the Pinterest Buyable Pins system, the special care that has to be given to PCI compliance with this system and the extreme amount of testing Pinterest requires of each integration before it can go live.

The only way for a Magento shop to participate in Pinterest Buyable Pins, then, is via the official Magento Pinterest Buyable Pins extension: https://info2.magento.com/Pinterest.html and http://creatuity.com/magento-pinterest-buyable-pins-for-magento/

If you're curious how it works behind the scenes, it doesn't use Magento's SOAP API at all. The Pinterest Buyable Pins system requires that your site has a specific, custom REST API running on a specific, secret endpoint. Pinterest then makes calls to that REST API to build a cart, get shipping options, place an order, etc. This is because on the Pinterest side of things, every integration with every platform works exactly the same - there can't be any platform-specific API calls.

Source: I wrote much of the code for the Pinterest Buyable Pins integration for Magento, alongside the rest of my team at Creatuity.